# Child Control is not rendering

Tags: c#, asp.net, custom-server-controls

I created a custom composite control that contains, among other things, child controls from this project https://googlevisnet.codeplex.com/ (it is a .NET library for google charts which i checked various times). I am using VisualStudio 2012 and a simple C# Class library.

I override CreateChildControl like so:

```
protected override void CreateChildControls()
    {
        Controls.Clear();

        //create the pie control
        GenderChart = new GVPieChart();
        GenderChart.Width = PieChartDimentions[0];
        GenderChart.Height = PieChartDimentions[1];
        GenderChart.ChartData(GenderDistributionTable);

        //create the bar control
        AgeChart = new GVColumnChart();
        AgeChart.Width = BarChartDimentions[0];
        AgeChart.Height = BarChartDimentions[1];
        AgeChart.ChartData(AgeDistributionTable);

        this.Controls.Add(GenderChart);
        this.Controls.Add(AgeChart);
    }
```

and override Render like so:

```
AgeChart.RenderControl(output);
```

When I run the code on the page everything seems to work, and i can tell that the control rendered the area correctly (i can see the div with the specific size), however I do not see the chart itself.

The weird thing is that for a moment there it was working and then stopped again without me applying any changes to the code.

Any Ideas?

Comment: Winforms? Webforms? WPF? Silverlight? Something else?

Comment: David, add tags to your question to indicate what technologies your problem is dependent on.

Comment: Thanks both, I tried to added tags such as Server Controls Composite Control, C#, but for most it didn't let me do it. I'll give it another shot.

Answer (score 2):

Apparently what solve the problem was something as stupid as adding the ID for the controls.
    protected override void CreateChildControls()
        {
            Controls.Clear();

```
        //create the pie control
        GenderChart = new GVPieChart();
        GenderChart.ID = "genderChar";
        GenderChart.Width = PieChartDimentions[0];
        GenderChart.Height = PieChartDimentions[1];
        GenderChart.ChartData(GenderDistributionTable);

        ////create the bar control
        AgeChart = new GVColumnChart();
        AgeChart.ID = "ageChart";
        AgeChart.Width = BarChartDimentions[0];
        AgeChart.Height = BarChartDimentions[1];
        AgeChart.ChartData(AgeDistributionTable);

        this.Controls.Add(GenderChart);
        this.Controls.Add(AgeChart);
    }
```

I don't know how i forgot something as essential as ID. Our mind stops to think simple at some point.

Cheers :)

Comment: Dude, it's not your fault...if a framework forces you to not forget doing certain unintuitive things, it sucks